# Why does UITableView cache cells when reloading data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

If you were to call `tableView.reloadData()` on a table with custom `UITableViewCell`, then it will cache those cells when you reload data. (It is discussed here: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXForms/issues/92)

If you continue reloading data, after a while, there could be 30/40 cells that are cached and retained. My question is: why is that?

In particular:

1) What possible usage could there be to retain cells that have since been lost after reloading the table?

2) What could be done to prevent/reduce the memory cache storing the cells?

3) Most importantly, why does this happen? Why would cells be retained when `reloadData()` is called?

#### Example

To give you a basic example in code, click on one of the cells, then, when you see the objects in memory, there are more retained cells:

`ViewController.Swift`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tableViewController = QuizTableViewController(style: .grouped)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupTableViewController()
}

private func setupTableViewController() {
    self.view.addSubview(tableViewController.view)

    let topAnchor = self.tableViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor)
    let leadingAnchor = self.tableViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor)
    let trailingAnchor = self.tableViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor)
    let bottomAnchor = self.tableViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topAnchor, leadingAnchor, trailingAnchor, bottomAnchor])
}
}
```

`QuizTableViewController.Swift`

```
import UIKit

class QuizTableViewController: UITableViewController {
override init(style: UITableViewStyle) {
    super.init(style: style)
    self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = QuizCell(subText: "HELLO WORLD")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "THIS IS WHAT IS DISPLAYED"
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

`QuizCell.Swift`

```
import UIKit

class QuizCell: UITableViewCell {
weak var subText: UILabel?

init(subText: String) {
    self.subText = UILabel()
    self.subText?.text = subText
    super.init(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "QuizCell")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

deinit {
    print("This is called after the cache is full.")
}
}
```

Comment: Using the code above, if you inspect the objects in memory, there are initially 5. After clicking on a cell, it will effectively double the number of cells in memory. So it is creating more cells than displayed on the screen.

Comment: The cell is reused not cached

Comment: @LeoDabus Cells are only deallocated after the cache has filled up. If you use the code above, then you will see that they are eventually deinitialised after the cache fills up, hence they cannot be reused, they must be cached. The cache fills up every time you click on a cell.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using the proper approach to creating table cells. You are explicitly creating a new instance of `QuizCell` in the `cellForRowAt`. What you should be doing is dequeueing a reusable cell using `dequeueReusableCell`. Then your issue goes away because the table will only keep the minimum number of cells needed.

Please find any one of the countless tutorials on using table views for proper examples.

Answer (score 0):

Like @rmaddy mentioned, the problem is how you are dequeuing the cell in `cellForRowAt` function. Instead, change it to something similar to:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuizCell", for: indexPath) as! QuizCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "THIS IS WHAT IS DISPLAYED"
    return cell
}
```